# using LME49990 with single supply

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am planning on using LME49990 amplifier for my Sigma Delta ADC front end. My problem is I don't have dual supply and I can provide only +5V. So Will it work with single supply. 
Will there be any performance degradation with single supply.

Comment: You could generate a negative supply from a positive voltage - take a look at http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/szzn001/szzn001.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide only +5V you need to find another op-amp or revisit the power supply situation.

[image: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lme49990.pdf]

It is not specified for less than 10V supply.

Also, the inputs won't necessarily work if you're outside maybe +/-1V even with a +/-5V supply (input common mode range) and the output won't necessarily swing higher than +/-2.5V with a 2K load (output voltage swing).

Op-amps that are specified with dual supplies will "work" with a single supply that exceeds the minimum total voltage and is less than the maximum total voltage (there is no 'ground' pin on most op-amps), but the inputs and outputs won't necessarily work as close to the supply rails as you might hope for. In other words, the op-amp might 'work' according to specs, but your circuit might not do what you hoped for.